# Tkinter canvas image works on windows but not OSX

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Somewhat beginner so pardon my mistakes.

I've created a super simple tk script, which creates a canvas and displays an image on it. It works on windows but not on OSX, The only difference being the filepath.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()

canv = Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg='white')
canv.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"C:\project\TechArt\tools\illustrator_label_browser\thumbnails\rachel_vector_lines.png"))  # PIL solution
canv.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=img)

mainloop()
```

OSX Mojave:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()

canv = Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg=‘white’)
canv.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(“/Users/jonathansundberg/Techart/tools/illustrator_label_browser/thumbnails/rachel_vector_lines.png”))  # PIL solution
canv.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=img)

mainloop()
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What are the error messages you got in OSX?

Comment: None, it runs just fine but the picture is not displayed

Answer (score -1):

I have macOS Mojave too. These three commands could help:

```
sudo easy_install pip
pip install Pillow
python3.7 -m pip install pillow
```

I was able to open jpeg file with your code and python3.7 command.

Comment: How did it fare with png files?

Comment: Yes, it works with png files too - I just tested it. The difference is not only the path, but the whole systems with different version of software. One must be conformable with command line on macOS to solve this problem: https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ The PIL package on macOS has multiple problems: google "python PIL mac"